# Syntax error on executing a script in Sybase database

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I created a **Sybase** database **emp_details** using SQL Anywhere and Sybase Central. I had given emp/emp as dba username/password while creating.

The db got created and the files were generated in the given folder.

When I tried running the below script using Ineractive SQL:

```
use master
go

if exists (select 1 from master..sysdatabases where name='emp_details')
    checkpoint emp_details
go
```

It threw the following exception

```
Could not execute statement.
Syntax error near 'checkpoint' on line 2
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000"
Line 4, column 1
```

Haven't been able to figure out what exactly the syntax issue is and have been stuck up with this for a while.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure CHECKPOINT takes no arguments

Comment: @AlexK. But this is something which has been running fine (not by us) till now. It should have thrown up this error then yea? anyways will try without the argument.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you may want to think about posting your SQL Anywhere questions to the http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/ forum.  It's a forum dedicated to the SQL Anywhere product line.

Is there any possibility that the two periods together might be causing your syntax issue?

Normally you're not going to get an exact area where the error is coming from.  See if that helps.  Also check out the other forum as well.